# how to select the element in drop down list (Data is inside div) in selenium

Tags: selenium, select, xpath, drop-down-menu

I am trying to automate selecting a value from a drop down list, but I'm having trouble.

HTML code:

```
<div ext:qtip="Contains R&amp;D normal users (User Permission)" class="x-combo-list-item  x-combo-selected" id="ext-gen257">User Addition</div>
```

I tried all steps to select this (Xpath, Absolute path, id, "User Addition", Tag selector). Nothing is worked for me.

How can I select a value from this dropdown?

Comment: `HTML` is missing

Comment: <div ext:qtip="Contains R&amp;D normal users (User access)" class="x-combo-list-item  x-combo-selected" id="ext-gen26">Users</div>

Comment: any updates on my issue

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you provided in your comments, the following should work through `Java` bindings:

1. **`xpath`** :

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected'][starts-with(@id, 'ext-gen')]"));
   ```
2. **`cssSelector`**

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected'][id^='ext-gen']"));
   ```

Comment: No dude it doesn't working. From that drop down menu i have 17 options this one is 15th can u suggest me something else.

Comment: That id value "ext-gen 257" is changing everytime

Answer (score 0):

Please give below xpath try:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected'][contains(text(), 'User Addition')]"));
```